# Write Specific SubItems to .txt while looping through ListView Control?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, foreach, listviewitem

My below code first writes an exclamation point (!) delimited Header to a .txt file and then loops through each item and subItem in a ListView Control, placing each record value onto a new line in my .txt file. All the values are needed for user review while in the ListBox, but when writing to the file, I need to only write the fields that are used in the next step, using the .txt file as datasource for MS Word MailMerge document.

Instead of looping through and appending every record field value to my StringBuilder, I need a way to get only the values where the ListView Column Header is the following:

**memno
name
address1
address2
address3
sal
fuldate
sys**

```
private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {    
                string docLoc = "";
                string docSource = "";
                StringBuilder sb;
                // Change this to the DataSource FilePath
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Test2.txt");
                string fileHeaderTxt = "memno!name!address1!address2!city!state!zip!old_addr1!old_addr2!old_city!old_state!old_zip!sys!fuldate!sex!lname!sal!address3";
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(fileHeaderTxt);
                sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();

                if (lvData.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem lvI in lvData.Items)
                    {
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvSI in lvI.SubItems)
                        {
                            sb.Append(string.Format("{0}!", lvSI.Text));
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
                //sb.Clear();
                sw.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Complete");

                if (rbPrint.Checked)
                {
                    Print(docLoc, docSource);
                }
                if (rbCommit.Checked)
                {
                    Commit_NetFYI();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Source:\t" + ex.Source + "\nMessage: \t" + ex.Message + "\nData:\t" + ex.Data);
            }
            finally
            {
                //
            }
        }
```

I've been hammering away at this for last couple hours and just can't seem to get it. Anyone have some ideas?

**EDIT:**

I modified my code using Grammarian's solution, but it seems I am missing something. Each loop iteration writes a line containing all previous looped values, plus the new value.

**Rough Example:**

Header1!Header2!Header3!Header4

1!2!3!4

1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8

1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!9!10!11!12

1!2!3!4!5!6!7!8!9!10!11!12!13!14!15!16
etc.

Here is my current code:

```
private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string docLoc = "";
                string docSource = "";
                StringBuilder sb;
                // Change this to the DataSource FilePath
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\NAME\\Desktop\\Test2.txt");
                string fileHeaderTxt = "memno!name!address1!address2!city!state!zip!old_addr1!old_addr2!old_city!old_state!old_zip!sys!fuldate!sex!lname!sal!address3";
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append(fileHeaderTxt);
                sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                sb.Clear();

                if (lvData.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (ListViewItem lvI in lvData.Items)
                    {
                        var indices = new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 12, 13, 16, 17 };
                        foreach (int i in indices)
                        {
                              sb.Append(string.Format("{0}!", lvI.SubItems[i].Text));
                        }
                        sw.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
                        sb.Clear();
                    }
                    sw.WriteLine();
                }
          }
    }
```

**EDIT2**:

Got it, wasn't clearing out my stringBuilder object after each time through my first loop. Edited code above to reflect working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than always just iterating all subitems, make an array of subitem indices in the order you want, and iterate the indices.

```
var indices = new [] { 0, 1, 2, 4, 9 }; // whatever you want
foreach (int i in indices)
{
    sb.Append(string.Format("{0}!", lvI.SubItems[i].Text));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grammarian! :) After using your example I was having a problem writing each previous loops sum values + the new value, but I got it figured out. Was forgetting to clear my stringBuilder object after finishing each iteration in the first loop :P